# Can registered ECC memory go into a desktop mother board?

Tags: memory, ecc

Can registered ECC memory typically go into a desktop mother board?

I don't really need ECC RAM, but the reason for asking is that I'm looking at a mother board that has 4 memory slots and supports up to 64gb of memory. This means that in order to actually get 64gb of memory into the machine, each memory chip would have to be a 16gb chip. When I go looking for 16gb chips, all I find are registered ECC chips meant for servers.

Specifically, the motherboard I'm looking at is the [ASRock 970 PRO3 R2.0 AM3+](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813157364)

All the 16gb RAM I could find is [here](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=100007952%20600006050%20600336949&QksAutoSuggestion=&ShowDeactivatedMark=False&Configurator=&IsNodeId=1&Subcategory=541&description=&hisInDesc=&Ntk=&CFG=&SpeTabStoreType=&AdvancedSearch=1&srchInDesc=).

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to ASRock's website, it doesn't support *buffered* (by which they mean *registered*[1]) memory: http://www.asrock.com/mb/AMD/970%20Pro3%20R2.0/?cat=Specifications

[1] Buffers were only used until the era of EDO-RAM. Nowadays, registers are used instead, but their purpose - reducing load on the memory controller on the mainboard - is basically the same.

Comment: Ah yeah, and it looks like they also have this comment implying the correct memory is not yet available: "**To reach the maximum 64GB of system memory, memory modules with 16GB capacity or above are required. ASRock will update the memory support list on the official website once these memory modules are available on the market."